# Reactor Netty HttpClient connect timeout is not working on Linux

Tags: netty, reactor-netty

I have been debugging connection timeout issues we have been having. I created a unit test and then noticed that when running on my Macbook (M1), the connect timeout works as expected. But when running the test on the build server (Linux), the test hangs as if no connect timeout was set

```
@Test
void nettyTimeout() {
    try (var serverSocket = new ServerSocket(0, 1); var clientSocket = new Socket()) {
        clientSocket.connect(new InetSocketAddress("localhost", serverSocket.getLocalPort()));

        var url = "http://localhost:" + serverSocket.getLocalPort();
        var httpClient = HttpClient.create()
                .option(ChannelOption.CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS, 2000);

        var startTime = Instant.now();

        httpClient.get().uri(url)
                .responseContent().aggregate().asString()
                .onErrorResume(throwable -> Mono.just("")).blockOptional();
        var timeoutDuration = Duration.between(startTime, Instant.now());

        System.out.println(timeoutDuration);
        assertTrue(timeoutDuration.toMillis() < 3000, "Timeout was longer than expected: " + timeoutDuration);

        httpClient = HttpClient.create()
                .responseTimeout(Duration.ofMillis(6000))
                .option(ChannelOption.CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS, 2000);

        startTime = Instant.now();

        httpClient.get().uri(url)
                .responseContent().aggregate().asString()
                .onErrorResume(throwable -> Mono.just("")).blockOptional();
        timeoutDuration = Duration.between(startTime, Instant.now());

        System.out.println(timeoutDuration);
        assertTrue(timeoutDuration.toMillis() < 3000, "Timeout was longer than expected: " + timeoutDuration);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        fail("Failed to start server socket:" + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

In the code above I am starting a server socket with a limit of one and then get one client to connect to it. I then create a Netty HttpClient with `ChannelOption.CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS` set to 2 seconds. Using this client I connect to the server socket to simulate connect timeout. On my Mac it works, and both tests times out after ~ 2 seconds.
On the build server (Linux) it hangs indefinitely and does not time out.
This correlates to behaviour I noticed that when I set `.responseTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(10))` on the client, it times out after 10 seconds instead of 2 on Linux.

What is the reason for the difference in behaviour and how can I set connectTimeout independently from responseTimeout?